# I want to know the difference between these two method invocations?

Tags: java

```
Node<T> node1;
Node<T> node2 = new Node();
node1.add(T element);//// 1
node2.add(T element); /// 2

// i want to know the differnece between 1 and 2
// @1 method invocation is through variable of class type Node
// @2 method invocation is through object reference.
```

Comment: both don't pass compilation.

Comment: These are not method invocations but syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's fix the biggest syntax errors:

```
Node<T> node1;
Node<T> node2 = new Node<T>();
//                      ^^^---- added type parameter
node1.add(element); /// 1
//        ^-------------------- no T here
node2.add(element); /// 2
//        ^-------------------- or here
```

There's no difference in the invocations (the calls to `add`) at all. The only difference is that you'll get a compiler error for #1 because you haven't assigned anything to `node1`. The javac compiler is smart enough to detect uninitialized variables. (Now, if those were instance fields in a class, `node1` would start out with the value `null` and you'd get a runtime error [a `NullPointerException`] *unless* `add` is a `static` method.)

> @1 method invocation is through variable of class type Node

That's mostly correct, the type of the variable is `Node<T>`, not just `Node`. It's also true for @2.

> @2 method invocation is through object reference

That's also correct. It's also true for @1. The variable, of type `Node<T>`, contains an object reference (assuming you initialize it to something other than `null`). The invocation is through that reference.

Comment: This is my real code.

Comment: @Ssumit: Then either A) It's not Java, or B) It doesn't compile.

Comment: i got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Node1 is just a reference not pointing at anything in the memory.
Node2 is a reference pointing at a a node, created by new Node()